# How to have a custom title bar and a TabWidget at the same time?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I have a program that is a `TabWidget` that calls different activities. The problem is it crashes when I call a class that already has its own custom title bar and gives me the error `java.lang.RuntimeException`:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cellphone/com.cellphone.Settings}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

How do you get around this problem? I want an android version of iPhone's menu bar (which is why I'm using the `TabWidget`) that also has its own custom title bar on every page.

EDIT: on my pages I'm using a custom title

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.imtrackinglayout);

    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
        R.layout.custom_title_3);
```

My program crashes on the requestWindowFeature line with the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting item name="android:windowNoTitle">true from theme.xml.
That should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, I dont believe i have a theme.xml in my folder. In my activities I call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

  setContentView(R.layout.settings);

  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
    R.layout.custom_title_4); to show my custom titles

Comment: @Sean- in that case look in styles.xml

Comment: This is my custom_style.xml that I use to set up the title bars for my activities     <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#1f1e1e</item>
    </style>
 
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">45dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: Is theme.xml a default file? because I don't know where theme.xml or styles.xml is located